# Romer & Romer shocks update

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, data-request

I'm wondering if any researcher has tried to update the Romer and Romer monetary shocks dataset until the most recent period. The only thing I've seen in this respect is the below reference (but there the extension in to 2007)

Wieland, Johannes. Updated Romer-Romer Monetary Policy Shocks: Monetary_shocks.zip. Ann Arbor, MI: Inter-university Consortium for Political and Social Research [distributor], 2021-03-23. https://doi.org/10.3886/E135741V1-84760

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the readme file inside the directory, I was able to find the original
[Wieland and Yang (2020)](https://johanneswieland.github.io/Papers/findamp.pdf) paper. The authors update the data to 2007, as you have said.

As for updating the shocks, I don't think anyone has done that yet.